# When using using reduce with ternary inside a map, I seem to have troubles

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reduce

this is to return an array of numbers that are the highest value of the arrays inside of the base array. I can get it to work when i use for statements. But I have tried to simplify it, and can't work out why it doesn't work. any help would be appriciated.

```js
    function largestOfFour(arr) {
      return arr.map((x) => x.reduce((a, c) =>  c > a ? c : a, 0));
    }
```

Example with input and output:

```js
const input = [
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,5,4,3,2,1],
  [1,7,3,4,5,6],
];

function findHighestElements(arr) {
    return arr.map((x) => x.reduce((a, c) =>  c > a ? c : a, 0));
}

console.log(findHighestElements(input)); // [5,6,7]
```

Comment: Please add input and expected output.

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the expected input and output? What do you get instead as an output?

Comment: `[[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9]]` -> `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` you haven't separated the arrays with commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reduce, you can do it by just `Math.max`. like this:

```js
function findMaxNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.map((x) => Math.max(...x));
}

let test = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];
console.log(findMaxNumbers(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have values smaller than zero, you need to remove the start value

```
x.reduce((a, c) =>  c > a ? c : a, 0)
                                   ^
```

or use a very small start value, like `-Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the max of all the maxes, you can reduce the reductions. If you just want the max's, map the reduction.

```js
const maxOfArray = a => a.reduce((a, c) => c > a ? c : a, -Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); // thanks to Nina
const conciseVLAZMax = a => Math.max(...a); // thanks to VLAZ 

let a = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [6, -1, -2],
  [3, 4, 5],
]

let maxs = a.map(maxOfArray);
let maxMax = maxOfArray(maxs);

console.log(maxs);
console.log(maxMax);
```

Comment: I'd just use `maxOfArray = xs => Math.max(...xs)` instead of `.reduce`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks VLAZ. Added. I think the OP was under the impression that there was an ternery-operator related error in the max function, so using the OP code has an explanatory advantage.